# Cucumber+TestNG and Cucumber+JUNIT comparison

Tags: cucumber

Can anyone please help me in understanding what is difference or advantages of using Cucumber+TestNG over Cucumber+Junit ?

Comment: U will get better luck in https://sqa.stackexchange.com/. There is just a difference in the runner implementations. Other than that it is just testng vs junit.

Comment: @Grasshopper , Can we use testng annotations like beforeclass ,beforemethod ,aftermethod etc in cucumber hooks?

Comment: in junit only beforeclass and afterclass will work. For testng, not sure, but guessing beforeclass afterclass suites should work. try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestNG and Junit are just a unit testing frameworks, when you use Cucumber with Junit you can use Junit Annotation/Assertions in step definition file and similarly when you use Cucumber with TestNG you can use TestNG Annotation/Assertions in step definition file.

Answer (score 3):

TestNG provides more Annotations Like @BeforeSuite .

TestNG it self provides support for Junit.

With Latest upgrade of cucumber(4.0) Cucumber - TestNg provides Parallel Execution at Scenario Level where as Junit provides at Feature level.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in both cases you would be writing the Test Steps using selenium and probably will use the classes inside JUnit or TestNG to run the cucumber Feature file.
As per my knowledge the only place I used such file was the when  I'm creating the TestRunner.java  class.

It's much easier to do with JUnit since you just have to import **org.junit.runner.RunWith** But if you are using TestNG you'll need to use dataProviders and go on a bit more complex path to create the TestRunner Class

Other than that there won't be any other differences since you will be using cucumber features for testing.

Due to the above mentioned advantage, I recommend to use JUnit + Cucumber + Selenium for your scripting

Answer (score 0):

I tried both but decided for JUNIT 4.12 (JUNIT 5 does not seem to work with cucumber yet). It has all that you need. But i have to test that parallel thing in Test NG i guess. ;)

I use Cucumber in a Spring Boot Project and therefore JUNIT did not cause any problems for me. I can hand over a browser instance over multiple classes here (@Autowired) and this makes my code so much more modularizable.

You may have more annotation-options with Test NG but somehow i have the feeling that more people work with JUnit, so you have more support and a bigger community here.